# VBA macro to Mass update multiple protected files with different filenames in the same network folder location

Tags: networking, location, protected

Very new to this so please help. Im trying to mass update files in a static folder location, many files in one folder.

What i want to do is run VBA macro in Excel 2010 to goto a network location folder, open the fist file in the folder.  Unprotect the workbook and worksheets call another marco to run changes then protect the worksheet close the file and then move onto the next file in the folder until all files have been corrected.

I have created the marco to make the changes, this is called "Edit"

File types are xlsm and the workbook and worksheet are password protected
How can i automatically run the macro to goto the network location and in series open each file, unprotect, call the macro, then re protect the document close file and move onto the next file until they are all updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the MacroRecorder while performing the tasks you've listed.  You can then pinpoint the exact lines of code you need to add in.

Comment: im trying to get the marco to goto a network location and open files, recording using the Marco recorder doesnt work here.